# Evalute method doesn't works on puppeteer code

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer js code which works fine and i would like to handle error when elements doenst exists cause i get the error below :

- Error: failed to find element matching selector "div > div > span > div > h1"

so i would like to save null value if the selector doesn't exist

1 : this is the first code that works

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

const name2 = await page.$eval('div > div > span > div > h1', ele => ele.textContent);
console.log(name2);

        if (name2 !== "Null") {
            fs.appendFile(
                "files/data.csv",
                ${name2}\n`,
                function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );
        }

}
```

2 : second method name value keep null

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

        let name = 'Null';
        try {
            name = await page.evaluate(
                (el) => el.querySelector("div > div > span > div > 
                h1").textContent,
                i

            );
        } catch (error) { }
        console.log(name);

        if (name !== "Null") {
            fs.appendFile(
                "files/data.csv",
                ${name}\n`,
                function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );
        }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I follow what the issue is. What are you trying to do here? What's the error?

Comment: with the first method i get Error: failed to find element matching selector "div > div > span > div > h1" cause on some element of loop the elements isn't available. So for those i would like to skip

Comment: OK, so what's the problem beyond that? Neither snippet makes a whole lot of sense--for the first one, you're looping over URLs and not doing anything with them, just querying the same `<h1>` repeatedly. Second snippet, you're passing in an integer `i` and trying to run `querySelector` on it. I don't think that'll work. Please [edit] the post to clearly explain what you're trying to achieve, provide a full snippet and the site you're working with, please so others can provide verifiable, working code to fix whatever problem you're having. Thanks.